# Android optimise memory with glide

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-glide

I a big problem of memory in my application. In my view, i load dynamically many avatar with Glide.

How i can free memory after the ImageView is loaded ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < profils.length(); i++, col++) {
if (col == column) {
    col = 0;
    row++;
}
ll = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_community, null);
param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
param.height = ((Globals.metrics.widthPixels - column) / column);
param.width = param.height;
param.rightMargin = 5;
param.topMargin = 5;
param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(col);
param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row);
profil = (JSONObject) profils.get(i);
avatar = profil.getString("avatar");
final int id_profil = profil.getInt("id");
final ImageView imgProfilAvatar = (ImageView) ll.findViewById(R.id.profilAvatar);
Glide.with(context)
    .load(avatar)
    .crossFade()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(imgProfilAvatar);

layout.addView(ll, param); }
```

Thx

Comment: No need to do it, Glide will automatically manage bitmap memory. To know more how Glide does it you can see my library https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/GlideBitmapPool

Comment: Are these in a list or something? You should only have but so many ImageViews actually rendered at any given time, and it shouldn't be enough to bog down your memory. You might want to check how you are managing the views themselves.